H5 signature error running pilot on Donkeycar
I have Donkeycar running on a Pi4, have captured data and successfully trained pilots on an Ubuntu workstation. When I put the pilots back on the Pi and run the Donkeycar code with the suggested command it fails with this error: "OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)".
This is the log:
File "/home/red/Red1/manage.py", line 279, in load_model
kl.load(model_path)
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/donkeycar/parts/keras.py", line 62, in load
self.interpreter.load(model_path)
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/donkeycar/parts/interpreter.py", line 176, in load
self.model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py", line 262, in load_model
return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 562, in __init__
fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/red/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 235, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 102, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)'**`

It seems that corrupted files or wrong format are the common cause. I am poking through the associated files trying to find the mismatch,any pointers very much appreciated.
